# Xpath: Get count of occurrence of non-sibling element

Tags: xpath

I have table elements in XML which are nested across different elements. These tables have unique id each, however the XML also has few xref tags referring to these tables

```html
<main>
 <supply>
  <table id="table1">
  <title>This is table1 </title>
  </table>
 </supply>
 .
 .
 <order>
  <table id="table2">
  <title>This is table2 </title>
  </table>
 </order>
 .
 .
 <maint>
  <table id="table3">
  <title>This is table3 </title>
  </table>
 </maint>
 .
 .
 .
 <xref xrefid="table2"/>
 <xref xrefid="table1"/>
</main>
```

The xrefid is same as the table id to which it needs to refer. In the output the xrefs should be replaced by count of occurrence of table element  and table title as shown:

```html
For
<xref xrefid="table2"/>
<xref xrefid="table1"/>

Expected Output:
Table2 This is table2
Table1 This is table1
```

I have made the following changes and i am able to fetch the table title correctly but somehow the count of the position of the table is not correct (say the xrefid is referring to the 2nd table in the XML )

```html
<text fixtext="Table"/>
<autocalc xpath="1 + count(//table[normalize-space(//table[@id=@xrefid]])"/>
<autocalc xpath="for $ap in ancestor-or-self::*[@xrefid][1]/@xrefid return (normalize-space(//table[$ap=@id]/title))"/>
```

The output that i am getting is:

```html
Table??? This is table2
Table??? This is table1
```

I need the count like Table2 or Table5 (instead of incorrect value Table???). I am unable to fetch the correct count of the order of occurrence of table which is referred by xref. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `//table[@id=//xref/@xrefid]/(@id | title/text())`

Comment: Hi, i have already fetched the title of the tables and i just need the count/position of the table which is being referred. Say xref has id for any table and that table is the 4th table in the over all XML then the output will be: Table4 "title of table4".  The above snippet displays all the available tables  ids and titles for each xrefs